# power series uniformly convergence on its radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis

[image: 1]

In the proof of this theorem, is it true that I can replace $R_1$ with R if R is a finite real number? The biggest change is that R might be an open interval, but I don't think it would change the proof.

Comment: No, of course you cannot and there are plenty of examples. Don't you think it would be very odd to take $\;R_1\color{red}<R\;$ if we could really take $\;R\;$ instead?

Comment: The power series may not converge for $x = R$ or $x = -R$. Then you can't replace $R_1$ with $R$. If the series converges _absolutely_ for $x = R$ (or $x = -R$, but those conditions are equivalent), then you can use $R$ in the proof.

Comment: Consider the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$.  The radius of convergence is $1$, but what happens when $x=1$?